# Customer testimonials - Embedded tweet vs custom design

Tags: info-visualisation, marketing, emotion, customer

Do you think that embedded tweets would work better than custom design to show testimonials?

Embedded tweet are live proof which people can see by clicking on embedded tweet and also embeded tweet can be Favorited and re-tweeted too. Though we can also add link to custom design testimonial but I think twitter embed looks more authentic and recognizable.

**Twitter embed example**

[image]

**Custom Design testimonial example**

[image]

Comment: It is so subjective that it is really a matter of taste. Unless your audience is more skeptical than others then you may want to go with the 1st option.

Comment: What if they delete their tweet?

Comment: @Devin - Yes that would be a problem. But I think there would less chances of that

Comment: Yes, the chances are low, but you should plan for it possibly happening. However, I think if you did embed tweets and just monitored it every so often, that would be okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the elements that are supposed to make it seem more 'credible' and 'trustworthy', they are:

- Images of the people (along with their name), which traditionally works better than having no images or an anonymous feedback. T
- Having a brand name associated with the feedback (i.e. Twitter) which is probably the more subjective part of the what different people might think about the brand.
- Having an actual way to contact the person, which allows the skeptical people to follow through and verify the testimony. Even though people probably won't go that far and do it, just having the means to do so seems to make it more credible.

I think if you can create those elements in a customized way as well then it probably doesn't matter what option you go with, although you might consider the cost and effort of implementing it.